# Proper-case first field

Tags: perl

My text files contains this one :

```
COcoNut,Other,900,21_7_2011,Coimbatore,TEINGKAAY
CotTon,Others,3500,21_7_2011,Coimbatore,PARUTTI
Maize,Others,1200,21_7_2011,Coimbatore,MAKKAACHOOLAM
Bajra,Other,1325,14_7_2011,Coimbatore,KAMBU
Jowar,Other,2750,14_7_2011,Coimbatore,CHOOLAM
Ragi,Other,910,14_7_2011,Coimbatore,KEIZHVARAKU
Coconut,Grade_I,650,12_7_2011,Coimbatore,TEINGKAAY GRADE ONNU
Copra,other,5300,7_7_2011,Coimbatore,KOPPARAI
Paddy,ADT_______36,950,15_7_2011,Madurai,NELLU ADT MUPPATTI AARU
Paddy,AST_16,950,15_7_2011,Madurai,NELLU AST PATINAARU
```

Here i had COcoNut, cotTon JOWar, etc.  But i want to print like this Coconut, Cotton, Jowar i.e., the first letter should be uppercase rather than remaining using regular expression in perl and not in any packages ....

And also you have seen 'Others' , but i want only 'Other' in that text files.  This also added with the above expression.

Then, this text files will read and write a same files i.e., to be overwrite in that files in perl scripts

Please any one suggest me

Comment: This question is poor. I can't see any code. Show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::InSitu;

my ( $in, $out ) = open_rw ( '/path/to/file' );

my $separator = ',';

while ( <$in> ) {
    my @fields = split ( $separator => $_ );

    $fields[ 0 ] = ucfirst lc $fields[ 0 ];
    $fields[ 1 ] =~ s/(?<=other)s//gi;

    print { $out } join ( $separator => @fields ) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: data_1.txt contains my data. Here i'm using read that files and write it on that same text files(data_1.txt). If there any possibilities please let me know. Coz, i tried that one but after writing process (>) it produces empty files

Comment: @Zaid: Thanks. I knew i could need it some day :)

Comment: @user678992: Notice, that I used IO::InSitu instead of a simple `open` to avoid emptying the file. Whenever you open a file for writing it is truncated.

Answer (score 2):

```
s/^([^,]*)/\u\L$1/;s/,Others,/,Other,/;
```

Comment: Works, but add an /i after the second regexp to also catch the 'other'

Comment: Thanks i worked ......... Will you please let me know how to read and write a text file in same file